# firestore security rules syntax for

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

what is the syntax for using the auth.uid as item path in firestore

in firebase it would be this:

```
data.child(auth.uid).val() == 'admin'
```

I tried in firestore this, but is not working

```
resource.data.request.auth.uid == 'admin'
```

thans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resource.data` is an object containing the data of document being read/written. If you are trying to read values of a field in that document then try:

```
allow read: if resource.data[request.auth.uid] == 'admin'
```

This rule will allow read operation if the field `request.auth.uid` is `admin`.